# If he entered another number

Tags: javascript, html

I’m setting up a new server, and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application.if he has entered a number other than this 3 for example number 9,how to print alert

```
if (text === "1") {
    console.log(numbers.reverse()); 
  }
  if (text === "2") {
    console.log(numbers.splice(1, 3)) 
  }
  if (text === "0") { 
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;
    }
    console.log(numbers);
  }
```

Comment: `if....else if... else if ....else` or use `switch`

Comment: if it presses another key to execute the function squared

Answer (score 0):

use - `switch`

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function func1(num) {
    switch (num) {
        case 0:
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;
            }
            console.log(numbers);
            break;
        case 1: console.log(numbers.reverse());
            break;
        case 2: console.log(numbers.splice(1, 3));
            break;
        default:
            alert("Sorry! the expression doesn't match any of the above cases");
    }
}


func1(6);
```

or if..else if..else statement.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function func1(num) {
  if (num == 1) {
    console.log(numbers.reverse());
  } else if (num == 2) {
    console.log(numbers.splice(1, 3));
  } else {
    alert("Else Block");
  }
}


func1(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) condition instead of nesting if conditions.

When you have alot of if conditions, its difficult to follow the code later, thereby making it difficult to maintain.

An example of how to convert the above code to a switch is:

```
switch(text) {
  case "1":
     console.log(numbers.reverse()); 
     break;
  case "2":
     console.log(numbers.splice(1, 3)) 
     break;
  //so on you can keep adding cases
}
```